# Image posting to API

Tags: android, face-recognition, api-design

I would like to post my image (It is named as `file`.) to Kairos API for recognition. I try to send a built in camera made `JPG` picture. I have already tested one of these photos with `Postman` and service can successfully process these images.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
            String subjectId = user;
            String galleryId = "users";
            String selector = "FULL";
            String multipleFaces = "false";
            String minHeadScale = "0.25";
            try {
                myKairos.enroll(image,
                        subjectId,
                        galleryId,
                        selector,
                        multipleFaces,
                        minHeadScale,
                        listener);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


           // dataCheck();
        }
```

I get following in logcat:

> 04-14 12:46:42.323 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/skia: JPEG HW
>   Decoder return Successfully!!
>       04-14 12:46:45.614 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 10.682MB for 2092136-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:46.999 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.020MB for 2008711-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:47.089 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.851MB for 4017406-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:47.517 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.853MB for 3352682-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:47.700 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 19.518MB for 5029018-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:47.858 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 20.270MB for 4141254-byte allocation
>       04-14 12:46:47.908 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/AsyncHttpClient: Passed contentType will be ignored because
>   HttpEntity sets content type
>       04-14 12:46:47.935 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51efc738) fps:0.17,
>   dur:5831.11, max:5831.11, min:5831.11
>       04-14 12:46:47.935 12969-12969/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x51efc738, api:1,
>   last queue time elapsed:5831.11
>       04-14 12:46:48.119 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: propertyValue:true
>       04-14 12:46:48.120 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /52.20.220.147:80;LocalPort=59844(10000)
>       04-14 12:46:48.120 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/52.20.220.147:80] tm:10
>       04-14 12:46:48.121 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.199.102:59844] connected
>       04-14 12:46:48.121 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:10000
>       04-14 12:46:48.121 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/System.err: rto value is too small:0
>       04-14 12:46:48.124 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: >doSendRequest
>       04-14 12:46:48.236 12969-13990/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: